# Override image of a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, properties, uiimageview, overriding

I am trying to create a subclass of `UIImageView` in Swift that shows an image retrieved from a custom property (coming from my model). The code I am using is the following:

```
class AvatarImageView: UIImageView {
    var userProfile: UserProfile?

    override var image: UIImage? {
        set {}

        get {
            return self.userProfile?.avatar
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. The image is never shown. I also tried a call to `setNeedsDisplay`, but no luck. I would be happy for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `userProfile`'s `didSet`.

```
class AvatarImageView: UIImageView {
    var userProfile: UserProfile? {
        didSet {
            guard let userProfile = userProfile else { return }
            image = userProfile.avatar
        }
    }
}
```

You have overrides `image`'`set` which triggers drawing image but it is empty. It means whatever you set, it will do nothing. For `get`, if you call `avatarImageView.image`, it will return `avatarImageView.userProfile.avatar`. That's all what you did.

What you want to do is setting image when you set your own model `userProfile`. `didSet` is invoked just after the value is set. So `userProfile`'s `didSet` is invoked everytime new value has set and I just call `UIImageView.image =` in `didSet`.

Read this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you! Can you explain why the other version does not work, though?

Comment: Thank you for the linked article, I did read that before posting. I understand that the empty setter is a problem, because there is no way for the view to know when the image actually changed. I still don't understand why calling `setNeedsDisplay` from the `userProfile`'s `didSet` doesn't work, though.

Comment: @BlackWolf What do you mean `doesn't work`? Are you calling `setNeedsDisplay` in `userProfile`'s `didSet` and `AvatarImageView` doesn't update the new set `userProfile.avatar`?

Comment: exactly. If I take my code from above and add a `didSet` to `userProfile` that contains a call to `setNeedsDisplay` I would expect it to refresh the view, which it doesn't - the imageview does not display the image.

Comment: Check `userProfile` is not `nil` and `avatar` is correct `UIImage`(non nil either). You don't need to call `setNeedsDisplay`. It will draw image in next main run loop event.